# Angular 2 Proper way to declare NgIf

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am using *ngIf to conditionally display a `<div>` tag in a template.

```
<div *ngIf="panel?.imageUrl"><img [src]="panel?.imageUrl" /></div>
```

Because I am using TypeScript, there is a "compile" time error "unused NgIf" if I do not declare NgIf in a @Component directive.
It compiles and works if I add NgIf to **ETHER** `viewProviders` or `providers` or `directives` (`directives: [NgIf]`).
My question is: what is the right way to declare NgIf and why?

Comment: Normally you don't need to declare it since it's part of the platform directives. Which version of Angular2 do you use?

Comment: I am using beta 9.

Comment: I think that I know the answer to this question. The problem is with linting, not with Angular. The linter is looking for unused variables, when it shouldn't in this situation. I am using angular2-seed (https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed), which I like a lot, but it's linting settings may be causing this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to add `NgIf` to providers. They are included in `PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES` which are available everywhere by default.